# Unable to mock a class with a method that chains an interface in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a class with Mockito that has a method which chains an interface. The class is mocked successfully but when it calls the interface a null pointer is thrown. The code looks as below:

```
 mock = Mockito.mock(MyProcess.class);
    process = mock.getProcess()
            .getService() //Interface throwing null exception
            .startProcessInstanceByKey("String argument");
```

I got this solution and tried to follow the example on the page below but its not working: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS

```
Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

// note that we're stubbing a chain of methods here: getBar().getName()
when(mock.getBar().getName()).thenReturn("deep");

// note that we're chaining method calls: getBar().getName()
assertEquals("deep", mock.getBar().getName());
```

The example above is not working

Comment: You've shown the example from the doc. Show how you followed the example and where it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

You need to mock the retuning `Service`, too. All external dependencies of you classes need to be mocked and if you doesn´t do this you get `null`.

```
processMock = Mockito.mock(MyProcess.class);
serviceMock= Mockito.mock(Service.class);

Mockito.doReturn(serviceMock).when(processMock).getService();
Mockito.doReturn(<VALUE>).when(serviceMock).startProcessInstanceByKey("String argument");
```

You need to mock every step with external values - this is how it works.